# How to save ouput of perf (Linux tool) to a file?

Tags: linux, bash, unix, ubuntu

I want to save results after running perf command,
eg.

> perf stat -B dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/null count=1000000 &> result1

I tried a couple of ways, like

```
    (perf stat -B dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/null count=1000000 &>result1) > result2
    (perf stat -B dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/null count=1000000 &>result1) 2> result2
    (perf stat -B dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/null count=1000000 &>result1) &> result2
    ((perf stat -B dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/null count=1000000 &>result1) &> result2) > result3
```

well, none of these actually gave me what I want.

The result is

Performance counter stats for 'dd if=`enter code here`/dev/zero of=/dev/null count=1000000':

```
    235.959041 task-clock                #    0.998 CPUs utilized          
            20 context-switches          #    0.000 M/sec                
   .........(too long, dont want to have all of them here)
   0.236448007 seconds time elapsed"
```

I just want to save these to the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`strace` shows that `perf` writes to file descriptor 0, so this should work:

```
perf stat -B dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/null count=1000000 0> result1
```