# Perf output cannot be redirected to file

Tags: linux, output, perf

I am working with perf (a Linux tool) on Ubuntu (12.0.4 LTS), 
and I am at the moment stuck trying to redirect the output of the tool to a file. 
This issue has been addressed in many posts but any of 
the proposed solutions did nto work for me.

What I am trying here is: trace stats of a pid 
and store them in a file. In one terminal I run the perf tool and on another I kill the perf process using kill -INT command (`sudo kill -INT $pid`). Inspired by different solutions on the web (e.g. [how to save ouput of perf (Linux tool) to a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13421985/how-to-save-ouput-of-perf-linux-tool-to-a-file)) I have tried different combinations of commands, such as:

1. `perf stat -o hhe.txt  -e minor-faults,major-faults,cs -p 14615`
2. `perf stat --output hhe.txt  -e minor-faults,major-faults,cs -p 14615`
3. `perf stat --output hhe.txt --append -e minor-faults,major-faults,cs -p 14615`
4. `perf stat -e minor-faults,major-faults,cs -p 14615 2> hhe.txt`
5. `perf stat -e minor-faults,major-faults,cs -p 14615 0> hhe.txt`
6. `perf stat -e minor-faults,major-faults,cs -p 14615 >> hhe.txt`

For all these commands which are run in sudo mode 
the output is not written to the file. I am not sure why. Maybe because of the kill command; but the following link says it works: http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.linux.kernel.perf.user/911

I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

1. I also use Ubuntu 12.04,  it may depends on your version of perf.

   The Perf verision of mine is 3.2.40.  (You can check it by:

   **perf --version**
2. Since mine is above version **3.x**, I have tried following commands, which works for me:

   **3>results.log perf stat -e cycles --log-fd 3 ls > ls.txt**

   So according to your case, you could try:

   **3>hhe.txt perf stat -e minor-faults,major-faults,cs -p 14615 --log-fd 3 ls > ls.txt**

Meanwhile, I found this post very useful:
    *What stream does perf use?*
    https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/89591/what-stream-does-perf-use

Hope this helps : )

Answer (score 2):

I just added these two parameters at the end of command it captured everything for me in 2 files. I am not sure why we need 2 different files here but I was not able to redirect everything into 1 file. 2> is for stderr and 1> is for stdout. You can try this and see if it works. I was able to capture what I wanted to with this:

```
2>temp.out 1>temp1.out
```

For example, your command may look like -

```
perf stat -e minor-faults,major-faults,cs -p 14615 2>temp.out 1>temp1.out
```